# Problems with the sample-function of Modelica

Tags: function, sample, modelica

I have a probably rather small problem! I want to sample a signal in Modelica and as we know, it provides a built-in  function for that called "sample".
So when I try to use an algorithm like the following, a fault pops up which says **'Attempting to call non-function sample as function'**.
Did I miss something or did I do something wrong over here?

`algorithm
  if sample(0,1) then
    x := y;
  end if;`

Comment: You should show your complete actual code.  My guess is that you have a variable of some kind in that model named `sample` and that shadowing the built-in function.

Comment: You were right! I actually called the model _sample_, which was obviously the problem! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

You can only use sample inside when equation for the conditional expressions.
Sample is not a function is a builtin operator:

```
  when sample(0,1) then
    x := y; // maybe reinit(x, y); is needed here.
  end if;
```

Comment: I am sorry, the when clause is actually what I had! But it still doesn't change the error I get!

Comment: Ok. What Modelica tool are you using?

Comment: The problem was caused of the fact, that I also called the model _sample_. Thank you anyways for your efforts!

Comment: That should not be a problem! But depends on the Modelica tool you're using.